# Firefox addon toolbar button disappears after first run

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a Firefox addon made with the add-on SDK.

https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/board-notes/

To add a toolbar button I use a popular library for the SDK toolbarbutton.js:

https://github.com/erikvold/toolbarbutton-jplib/blob/master/lib/toolbarbutton.js

I only want to add the icon when it first installs and it works, the icon appears but after restarting the browser the icon disappears. The user has to use the right click button to open the setup browser bar and drag the icon again to the bar. Then if he restarts the icon continue correctly in its place.

I want to fix this behaviour because the most part of users probably don't know that they can recover the icon with the setup options.

I've tested some functions to detect if the icon is not in his place to move again, but by doing this if the user hides the icon, when he restarts it will appear again. And this is forbidden by Firefox policies.

I'll appreciate any help, I'm going crazy.

The code I use is this:

```
 button = createButton(options);

 if (options.loadReason == "install")
 {
    button.moveTo({
       toolbarID: "nav-bar",
       insertbefore: "home-button"
    });
 }

 function createButton(options) {
   return toolbarbutton.ToolbarButton({
     id: "NoteBoard",
     label: "Note Board",
     tooltiptext: "Note Board",
     image: data.url("noteboardMini.png"),
     onCommand: function() {
         openPopup();
     },
     onContext: (function () {
       var installed = false;
       return function (e, menupopup, _menuitem) {
       //Install command event listener
         if (!installed) {
            menupopup.addEventListener("command", function (e) {
               var link = e.originalTarget.value;
               if (link) open(link.replace(/\?.*/ , ""));
            });
            installed = true;
         }
         var temp = (function (arr) {
            arr.forEach(function (item, index) {
               for (var i = index + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
                  if (arr[i] && item.label == arr[i].label) {delete arr[index]}
               }
            });

         return arr.filter(function (item){return item});
    })(loggedins);
    //remove old items
     while (menupopup.firstChild) {
      menupopup.removeChild(menupopup.firstChild)
     }
     function addChild (label, value) {
      var item = _menuitem.cloneNode(true);
      item.setAttribute("label", label);
      item.setAttribute("value", value);
      menupopup.appendChild(item);
    }
    if (temp.length) {
      temp.forEach(function (obj) {
        addChild(obj.label, obj.link);
      });
    }
    else {
      addChild(_("context"), "");
    }
  }
 })()
 });
}
```

Comment: I am working on it, I will probably have an answer by tomorrow.

Comment: Does your `onContext` function run? When is this `onContext` supposed to happen?

I have not yet found anything to handle it in the library you linked to.

Comment: @Stephen I don't know what is the onContext function, I copied of another extension I use like an example of the icon bar, I don't see any call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the library [Toolbar Button Complete](https://github.com/Geek-in-Training/Toolbar-Button-Complete-jplib/), which is my fork of toolbarbutton.js.

## Using the library

You can use this library the same way as the original toolbarbutton.js, but it also has more options and features.

In your main.js file:

```
button = createButton(options);

// On install moves button into the toolbar
if (options.loadReason == "install") {
    button.moveTo({
        toolbarID: "nav-bar",
        insertbefore: "home-button",
        forceMove: true 
    });
};
```

You can find a working example of the library [here](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/167058/), but it is a bit out of date.

## Installing the Library

**If you are using the add-on SDK on your computer:**

1. Download [Toolbar Button Complete](https://github.com/Geek-in-Training/Toolbar-Button-Complete-jplib/archive/master.zip) from [github.com](http://github.com).
2. add it to your `packages` directory. *(Either under your SDK directory or under your add-on's directory.)*

**If you are using the [Add-on Builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org) to create your add-on**:

1. Click the plus button next to your library folder:

   [image: The plus button.]
2. Type in `Toolbar Button Complete`.
3. Click on the Add Library button:

   [image: Add Library Button]

## Updating the Library

The library is hosted on [github.com](http://github.com) [here](https://github.com/Geek-in-Training/Toolbar-Button-Complete-jplib/).

If you are using the [Add-on Builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org) for your add-on, you can simply click the little refresh button when there is an update available.

Comment: Thank you very very much @Stephen, with this toolbarbutton.js version the icon works correctly. Doesn't dessapear after first run and if the user wants to hide it he can. I've deleted the onContext function, it's not necessary, it works well without it. Now I have to wait the revision, I'm on 250 queue position! Thank you again!

Comment: @Oscardrbcn Sorry I am a bit late to tell you, but I just found out the one area I overlooked before releasing [Toolbar Button Complete](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/166563/). I didn't test it using more than one Firefox window, which it was not able to handle.  I have fixed it now, and you probably want to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: I didn't have any problem with more than one firefox window but I've upgrade to the last version and submit again. When I upload to the addon library I had a warning about compatibility in the line "const { isPrivate } = require("sdk/private-browsing");". I didn't find anything more about this private const and I've deleted this line to remove the warning. Did I do wrong? Thank you again!

Comment: No that is fine.  That was part of a work in progress anyways, I did not mean to put that in the stable channel.

Comment: @Oscardrbcn You probably want to update your addon (again) with the [latest version](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/166563/). Until this update it would do two things: **1:** It would freeze firefox if you installed it with more than one Firefox window open, and **2:** It caused other addons' toolbar button to disappear. (TileTabs for example.)

Comment: @Stephen works great, thanks for putting in the work for this. Is this hosted on github or anywhere similar so I can follow the source?

Comment: @andrew It isn't currently, just an builder.addons.mozilla.org for now. But I have been planning to put it up on Github for awhile. I will let you know if/when I do!

Comment: @andrew I now have it [hosted on github](https://github.com/Geek-in-Training/Toolbar-Button-Complete-jplib/)!